# How does importlib.h generated from importlib._bootstrap in Cpython?

Tags: import, cpython

I am rewriting python import system in C. I encountered a problem: in `Python/importlib.h`, it says it is generated by `Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py`, but even if I changed some code in `Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py`, `Python/importlib.h` remains unchanged.

I have 3 questions:

1: How can I change the bytecode in `Python/importlib.h`?

2: What is the relationship between `Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py` and `Python/importlib.h`?

3: How does the cpython import system work in total?

Comment: you have to build and run https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Programs/_freeze_importlib.c. Did you do it?

Comment: And "How does the cpython import system work in total?" sounds like quite a complicated question which is not well suited for SO.  See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several weeks of reading the source code of Python-3.6.10, I write an answer here to offer my understanding.

1. `Python/importlib.h` is generated by `Programs/_freeze_import.c`. "make regen-all" is need to rerun the _freeze_import.c file. `_freeze_import.c` take the input of `Lib/importlib/*.py` to generate `Python/importlib.h` and `Python/importlib_external.h`.
2. `Lib/importlib/*.py` is the source of `Python/importlib.h` and `Python/importlib_external.h`.
3. You need to dive into the source code.